# Pagination buttons are not always working in Safari

Tags: bug

I am using the new tab system on the main page and when I try to switch between pages, I usually only can do it for the second or third try, other times it just scrolls to the top. I am using Safari 12603.1.30.0.34 on macOS 10.12.4.